# Count the subsets of [n] whose sum is modulo $2^k$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Prove that for all $k \geq 1$ and $n \geq 2 ^{k-1}$, the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3\cdots n\}$ with sum congruent to $i$ mod $2^k$, equals the number with sum congruent to $i+1$ mod $2^k$, for all $0\leq i\lt2^k$.

P.S.

i do not know the math around it, but this is how the number of subsets with sum congruent to $i$ mod $2^k$ behaves for different values of $n$.
The header row column values indicate the sum congruent to $i$ mod $2^k$ values.
In each row, the first column indicates the value of $n$.

In this example, $k = 3,2^k=8$ and $n$ varies from $1$ to $6$

```
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

    1  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    2  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  
    3  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 
    4  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
    5  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
    6  8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Th table is constructed using the recurrence relation, $S_{n,i} = S_{n-1,i} + S_{n-1,(i-n) mod 2^k}$, if we assume $S_{n,i}$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3 \cdots n\}$ with sum congruent to $i$ mod $2^k$.
From the table, we can observe that for $n\geq4$ i.e. $2^{k-1}$, all the entries of the row are equal.
And if we look closely, each entry is $2^{n - k}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Prove it for $n = 2^{k-1}$ by using $$(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)...(1+x^{2^{k-1}}) \pmod{x^{2^k} - 1}$$
and showing it is equivalent to $2^{2^{k-1} - k}(1 + x + ... + x^{2^k-1})$ via plugging in the $2^{k}$th roots of unity. Then apply induction to get the desired result, $n = 2^{k-1}$ being your base case.

Comment: Thank you for responding. But, i do not know how to do it.

Comment: Which part do you not know how to do? The base case or the inductive step?

Comment: Please help me understand the base case. Thanks.